# What does $\times$ represent in $\mathcal{L}(G\times G)= \mathcal{L}(G)\oplus\mathcal{L}(G)$?

Tags: notation, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am getting slightly confused about the nature of $\times$ in Lie algebras and representations in general. From what I can tell $\times$ is used by some authors to represent both the Cartesian product or the tensor product (in the context of Matrix Lie groups). For example in the formula:

$$\mathcal{L}(G\times G)= \mathcal{L}(G)\oplus\mathcal{L}(G)$$
Is the $\times $ a Cartesian product or a tensor product? Is there even some sort of isomorphism between them so that this ambiguity doesn't actually matter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have literally never seen the symbol $\times$ used to denote a tensor product.  I would assume that in the equation you wrote, $G$ is a Lie group and $\mathcal{L}(G)$ denotes the Lie algebra of $G$, in which case $G\times G$ definitely refers to the Cartesian product of $G$ with itself, which is again a Lie group (there is no such thing as a tensor product of Lie groups!).

Comment: (+1) For saving me the trouble of writing the same thing. ;-)

Comment: Ok fair, the other place I have seen this is as follows; in the context of representations on the Lie algebra of a matrix lie group:
$$r_{v\otimes \tilde v}(T)=r_V(T)\times I+I\times r_{\tilde v}(T)$$ From what I can tell these $\times$ should be tensor products is that correct?

Comment: Yes, in standard notation those $\times$ would be $\otimes$ instead.